# Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? Return correct century

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? Return correct century. This is intended to return the correct century, (e.g. year 1905 returns 20, year 1700 returns 17). Constraint is 1 ≤ year ≤ 2005. Input is a positive integer (year).

```
    function centuryFromYear(year) {
    switch (year) {

    case ((year >= 1) && (year < 101)):
    return 1;
    break;

    case ((year > 100) && (year < 201)):
    return 2; 
    break;

    case ((year > 200) && (year < 301)):
    return 3;
    break;

    case ((year > 300) && (year < 401)):
    return 4;
    break;

    case ((year > 400) && (year < 501)):
    return 5;
    break;

    case ((year > 500) && (year < 601)):
    return 6;
    break;

    case ((year > 600) && (year < 701)):
    return 7;
    break;

    case ((year > 700) && (year < 801)):
    return 8;
    break;

    case ((year > 800) && (year < 901)):
    return 9;
    break;

    case ((year > 900) && (year < 1001)):
    return 10;
    break;

    case ((year > 1000) && (year < 1101)):
    return 11;
    break;

    case ((year > 1100) && (year < 1201)):
    return 12;
    break;

    case ((year > 1200) && (year < 1301)):
    return 13;
    break;

    case ((year > 1300) && (year < 1401)):
    return 14;
    break;

    case ((year > 1400) && (year < 1501)):
    return 15;
    break;

    case ((year > 1500) && (year < 1601)):
    return 16;
    break;

    case ((year > 1600) && (year < 1701)):
    return 17;
    break;

    case ((year > 1700) && (year < 1801)):
    return 18;
    break;

    case ((year > 1800) && (year < 1901)):
    return 19;
    break;

    case ((year > 1900) && (year < 2001)):
    return 20;
    break;

    case ((year > 2000) && (year <=2005)):
    return 21;
    break;



}

}
```

Comment: Change it to `switch (true)`, otherwise you need to use an `if..else if` chain.

Comment: You’re misunderstanding how `switch` works. Anyway, the entire function body can be reduced to `return Math.ceil(year / 100);`.

Comment: thanks, that works. However, whats the problem with 'switch (year)'

Comment: @monsterreh2b Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). When you switch on `year`, the `case`s need to match possible values for `year`. `1996` is a possible value; `(year > 1900) && (year < 2001)`, which evaluates to `true`, is _not_.

Comment: Are you sure 1700 is 17th century? 1700 supposed to be 18th century. 1900 is 20th, 2000 is 21st.

Comment: @Xufox thanks for that

Comment: @MarinaDunst No, [it’s correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century#Start_and_end_in_the_Gregorian_Calendar).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `case` if you want to check range, it needs exact values.

```
switch (expression) {
  case value1:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches value1
    [break;]
  case value2:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches value2
    [break;]
  ...
  case valueN:
    //Statements executed when the result of expression matches valueN
    [break;]
  default:
    //Statements executed when none of the values match the value of the expression
    [break;]
}
```

A more general solution for your problem would be something similar to this:

```
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    return Math.floor((year-1)/100)+1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just divide the `year - 1` by a `100` and add `1` like this:

```js
function centuryFromYear(year) {
    return Math.floor((year - 1) / 100) + 1;
}


/* Example: */

var year = parseInt(prompt('Enter a year: '));

alert('The century is: ' + centuryFromYear(year));
```

Comment: For 1900 it returns 19, for 2000 it returns 20.

Comment: @MarinaDunst I had it to alert 21 if the year is 2000, but then I saw OP code and it appears that this what he actually wants. Check OP code! I think I'll just change it back to the way I had it. You opinion assured me that my first answer was the right one. l'll change it back.

Comment: Got it. I think the OP is mistaken.

Comment: @MarinaDunst I changed my answer to print to correct result. His code didn't make sense anyway!

Comment: I think I was mistaken

Comment: @MarinaDunst shoud change it back again?

Comment: Yeah I should ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21st_century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/21st_century))! OP was right. OP was right.